# Get return code and status from bash script into Java file

Tags: java, bash, shell, javafx

I am working in JavaFX scene builder App where at some point my code flow execution is like below:

From my Java class a bash script script1 called
From `MyClass.java`

```
exec(./Script1)
```

in 
script1 an another script script2 called

```
called ./script2
```

script2 an another script script3 called

In
script3

```
if [ ! "$upgrade_file_path" = "" ]; then
    echo "BUILD SUCCESS"
    echo "upgrade.cpio.gz : "$upgrade_file_path
    //LINE-1
else
    echo "FAILED TO CREATE upgrade.cpio.gz"
fi
```

What I need :

LINE-1 : Can I return some exit code from here to my java file (MyClass.java), I need to show the **BUILD SUCESS** string along with `$upgrade_file_path` and an exit code in my javafx label. 
Or I can save this exit code,path and status in a string in my `MyClass.java` file?

**Update:**

I am using an external jar to connect SSH. What I am trying to do is to connect a linux machine from my windows machine, and to achieve this I have used sshexec.jar [https://code.google.com/p/sshxcute/downloads/list](http://see%20this%20llink)

where below code does the job of connecting and executing the bash script

```
        ConnBean cb = new ConnBean(buildServerURL, buildServerUsername,buildServerPassword);
        // Put the ConnBean instance as parameter for SSHExec static method getInstance(ConnBean) to retrieve a singleton SSHExec instance
        ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);          
        //Connect to server
        ssh.connect();
        CustomTask sampleTask = new ExecCommand("/usr/init/checkout.sh");
        //Execution of main taks
        Result rs = ssh.exec(sampleTask);
```

Comment: There are good examples in the page for the project you are using: https://code.google.com/p/sshxcute/  (3.5 and 3.6). Did you look at them? Did you try using what is shown there?

Comment: Yes! rc (result code will print 0 if the last command gets executed), what I am trying to do is in my script I have written exit 5; I want this value 5 in result code. That is not happening with rc here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to execute shell command from java we need to use some library, in your case you are using SSHExec, in this jar you can have the result/exit code that is returned from the shell script.

```
if [ ! "$upgrade_file_path" = "" ]; then
    echo "BUILD SUCCESS"
    echo "upgrade.cpio.gz : "$upgrade_file_path
    //Here you can just add something like:
    exit 0;
else
    echo "FAILED TO CREATE upgrade.cpio.gz"
    exit 1;
fi
```

when the above scripts executes an exit code will be thrown from here and you can have this exit code in your java application something like this:

```
    ConnBean cb = new ConnBean(buildServerURL, buildServerUsername,buildServerPassword);
    // Put the ConnBean instance as parameter for SSHExec static method getInstance(ConnBean) to retrieve a singleton SSHExec instance
    ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);          
    //Connect to server
    ssh.connect();
    CustomTask sampleTask = new ExecCommand("/usr/init/checkout.sh");
    //Execution of main taks
    Result rs = ssh.exec(sampleTask);
    int exitCode = rs.rc; //rc stands for result code, and this rc will have what shell returned.rc is not a function but a int variable of Result class.
    if(exitCode!=0){
      //Error message
}else 
     //Success message.
```